# What does ceill floor in this code mean?

Tags: java

Can anybody explain me what does this code mean? In if/else. I have read documentation several times, but can't get what does these functions mean. Thanks.

```
private long getBalanceWithFactor(long balance, double factor) {
        double faccountbalance = (double)balance * factor;
        long res = 0;
        if ((Math.ceil(faccountbalance) - faccountbalance) <= 0.5)
            res = (long)Math.ceil(faccountbalance);
        else
            res = (long)Math.floor(faccountbalance);
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: docs, docs, docs, docs...

Comment: Please read the java API docs

Comment: That is the same as `Math.round(balance * factor)` or am I missing something?

Comment: it does the same as: res = (long) (facountbalance +0.5);

Comment: @JorisW That works for positive numbers, you need to `- 0.5` for negative values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Math.ceil()` rounds up, `Math.floor()` rounds down to the nearest integer.

So for example if you give it `0.5`

`ceil(0.5)` will return `1.0`, and `floor(0.5)` will return `0.0`.

There is another useful function in this context: `Math.round()` which is `ceil()` and `floor()` combined. It rounds to the nearest integer using the mathematical rounding rules.

**Please note** that these methods will return doubles so you'll need to cast them to get integers.

Comment: @whomever downvoted: care to explain?

Answer (score 1):

`Math.ceil()` - Returns the smallest (closest to negative infinity) double value that is not less than the argument and is equal to a mathematical integer.

`Math.floor()` - Returns the largest (closest to positive infinity) double value that is not greater than the argument and is equal to a mathematical integer.

Taken from [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html), check this for information on Math class and the methods that are defined in it.

For example,

`Math.ceil(5.8)` gives 6 and

`Math.floor(4.3)`will give 4

Answer (score 1):

ceil is the upper normalization ie ceil of 7.6, 7.1 is 8
floor is the opposite and means is the upper normalization ie ceil of 7.6, 7.1 is 7

This methd return integer number not float of the multiply of balance and factor

Answer (score 1):

It calculates balance*factor as `faccountbalance` and rounds it to the nearest integer.

If the value is <= 5 rounds to the prev long (floor).

If the value is > 5 rounds to the next long (ceil).